Did any notable disk operating systems other than Commodore DOS (as found on e.g. 1541) offer control of interleave when writing
On disk drives without track-caching logic, a request to read or write a sector will wait until the header of the requested sector passes under the drive head and then read or write the data that immediately follows the header.  If, after reading or writing a sector, the next sector passes under the drive head before the system is ready for it, the disk will need to make another revolution before that next sector can be read or written.  If the data for a file were written to consecutive sectors, most systems would be unable to process the data from each sector fast enough to be ready for the next sector before it passed under the drive head, thus making it necessary for the drive to make more than a full revolution for each sector read.
To alleviate this, floppy and hard drives without caching controllers would write consecutive sectors in a file to physically non-consecutive sectors.  On some systems, this is accomplished by formatting disks so that the sector numbers written to each track will be non-consecutive.  On others (e.g. Apple DOS 3.3) this is done by having the OS write sector markers in sequential order, but having the OS translate a request to e.g. read "sector 4" by using a lookup table which scrambles the sector order.  Commodore's drives, however, number sectors in physical order, but have a configurable setting for what interleave value should be used when writing files.
If one had some files which would be read by a fast program, and others which would be processed by a slower program, using the same interleave for all files would either cause the first program to run slower than would be necessary with a smaller interleave, or cause the second program to run much slower than necessary with a larger interleave factor.
I don't know whether any software for Commodore PET or VIC-family machines was set up to exploit the ability to write different files with different interleave settings, but the drive is designed in a way that would allow software to do so.  Did any disk operating systems (whether for floppy or hard drives) for other machines do likewise?

On a PC, interleave is also affecting track-to-track re-alignment. (i.e. how "well" the head hits a specific sector in the next track when it moves in or out. On a 1541, this is totally irrelevant because the tracks have no in-between alignment because the drive doesn't use the index hole.

Not an answer to your actual question but the strategy taken to compensate for variable read rates by a number of modern 1541 fastloaders is to read out-of-order, that is opportunistically picking up any future sectors under the read head from a contiguous transaction. Some, such as Spindle, even decompress the sectors individually out-of-order. Another strategy is to read in-order with a conservatively high interleave and prioritize using the CPU for IEC transfers over decompression whenever the former is available.

@doynax Floppy extenders that have enough memory (more than the scarce 2K the original had) normally ignore interleave completely and read whole tracks at once, then  pick what they need from memory and send it to the host. But, for "the original" both the available bandwidth to the host computer and the available memory on the drive don't allow that.

So those old computers didn't have enough memory to cache a 9K track, so they deliberately degraded performance horribly by doing multiple reads on an interleaved floppy? Or do I not understand it? Damn, memory was tight back then.

@Miss Understands: A computer itself had the memory but not the original drive, which is a small embedded system itself on a C64. The bottleneck was the slow software-operated serial bus between the two preventing the computer from keeping. Unless using lower-density magnetic coding than normal and dedicating 100% CPU on to the transfer anyway.

@doynax So in those days, a 9K track buffer was an expensive component for a disk controller? God, I forgot how expensive memory was. My computer has a larger screen buffer than my university mainframe had mass storage.

On x86 PCs with MS-DOS, the OS itself did not. However, you could run a custom program like fdformat which allowed to low-level format floppies with any interleave factor possible. Interleave factor was generally selectable when low-level formatting hard drives using the disk controller BIOS, such as MFM drives on an AT-compatible 286 system. Does this count for an answer?

The (Apple II) Apple Disk 3.5" could be formatted with any interleave from 1:1 to 13:1, with 2:1 and 4:1 being most common.  The UniDisk 3.5" used a default 4:1 interleave when formatting but this could be adjusted by overwriting the variable in UniDisk's RAM.  This was a volume setting, not a per-file setting.

@Justme: Because MS-DOS allocates clusters but buffers sectors, there would be no way to have different files on an MS-DOS floppy stored using different interleave values unless they were stored on tracks that were formatted differently.  While it would be possible to format different tracks with different interleave values, there would be no nice way to have the system prioritize storage of different kinds of files on different tracks.

@supercat As most floppy disks have cluster size of 1 sector, you could "defrag" or rather "enfrag" the files yourself, to have filesystem level interleave on the hardware sectors. Of course then you can't say to the floppy drive controller to read multiple contiguous sectors, but I am unsure if DOS even reads multiple sectors contiguously if possible or does it read only single sectors.

@Justme: Under MS-DOS, single-sided disks have a cluster size of 1, but I'm pretty sure I remember double-sided disks as generally having a cluster size of 2, and thus always had an amount of free space that was a multiple of 1024 bytes.  Was I imagining that?

@supercat Just typed CHKDSK on 1.2 and 1.44 MB floppies in MS-DOS 6.22 - both have 512 bytes in each allocation unit, for 2371 and 2847 allocation units respectively.

I remember that DD floppies (160K/180K/320K/360K/720K) used 2 sectors/cluster, but HD floppies (1.2MB/1.44MB) used 1 sector/cluster.

Does this make sense at all? As a long-term developer I would not dare to let my programs announce themselves as "fast" or "slow" writing/reading. On some really limited systems like early home computers, perhaps, with a limited set of file types.

At the time of writing files the sector numbering is already fixed, because this happens during formatting. Does the Commodore drive format when writing files? Oh-oh. However, interesting question, because it sheds some light on this drives.

Would you mind to [edit] your question to add details about the public interface of the Commodore drive?

@thebusybee: Modern computers all have enough buffering to easily support 1:1 interleaving, but on older machines, using a higher interleave than necessary for a task would increase I/O times by a factor of 25%-50%, and using lower than necessary for a task would increase I/O times by a factor of three or more (on a 16-sector floppy using 4:1 interleave, reading 4096 bytes would require about a second; using 3:1 but missing timing constraints would take almost four seconds.  Most programmers of that era probably viewed disk drive performance as an unchangeable fact of life...

...but software that was aware of interleaving woudl have been able to achieve much better performance than available otherwise.  It would also have been possible in many cases to trade off read and write performance.  It might be possible to either spend ten seconds writing a file in a way that could be read in one, or spend two seconds writing a file that would then take two seconds to read; for files which will be read many times, the former would make more sense, but for files which will be read only once, or (for backup files) never be read at all, the latter would make more sense.
